# How to create an installer and uninstaller for a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, uninstallation

I created an installer for my Windows Forms application and I added the project output to programs menu. But now what I want is 'I should have a folder in programs menu in that it should contain both install and uninstall options'.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um - I may be being dense here - but what is placing the "Install" shortcut in the menu - if not an install? Or what does it mean to do an install, after you've already installed the software. *Usually*, you'd create a folder with a shortcut to launch the application and (optionally) an uninstall shortcut.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to create a Setup and Deployment project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

I have to agree with Sir Richard's answer, but I wanted to add the instructions on how add an uninstaller using the Setup and Deployment project found in Visual Studio.

Here's a useful link you can work on: **[How to add a Uninstall option in Visual Studio Setup project without writing code](http://www.gogototo.com/how-to-add-a-uninstall-option-in-visual-studio-setup-project-without-writing-code.html)**

Comment: It's better to add the link as a comment to Richard's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try with NSIS, is open source and very easy...

"NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) is a professional open source system to create Windows installers. It is designed to be as small and flexible as possible and is therefore very suitable for internet distribution."

in his website you can find tutorials and examples, the link is: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

I hope this help you!

Comment: You are answering a 5+ year old question with a simple link. Usually, this is regarded as a bad practice, since you are providing no real value here. Could have been a comment instead.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I cant comment the question, so for that reason i wrote an answer. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have advanced scenarios that the Setup and Deployment project can't handle, I'd advise looking into [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/).

WiX is an extremely mature Microsoft opensource project, having first launched in 2004 and is still active today. It even provides a VS extension to assist you with getting started and intellisense for the configuration.

Be warned though: WiX primarily uses XML files that use MSI's domain language. It's certainly not a tool you use if "create an installer" wasn't allocated specifically in your project plan.